# What are the consequences of returning an IO action?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, io-monad

In Haskell, the type constructor `IO` is a monad equipped with a `return` statement that lifts any expression to its `IO` version.

Nothing prevents us from lifting what is already an `IO` action to its `IO` version - giving us a type of the form `IO (IO a)`.

So I can for example write the following program:

```
main = return . print $ "Hello world"
```

Which upon execution does exactly nothing.

My question is, what happens under the hood when this main is executed?

Are there any situations where it makes sense to `return` an IO action?

Comment: Small nitpick: it's a `IO (IO a)`.

Comment: @Zeta thanks! now fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IO` is often approximated to `State RealWorld`, that is a `State` monad that operates on the "real world". `return` for `State` produces an action that does not alter contained state. So, by analogy, `return`ing anything to `IO` doesn't do anything as well. Not only when you `return` some `IO a`, but any `a`.

Returning an `IO` action may be used to build up a computation in one place (capturing some values into a closure along the way) and execute it somewhere else. Much like passing a callback in C.

Actually, to build up an `IO` computation and pass it somewhere else you can use a `let` inside of a do-block:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let act = readFile "somefile" -- action is not performed yet
  foo act -- pass the action as a parameter

foo :: IO () -> IO ()
foo act = do
  .. do something
  result <- act -- actually perform the action
  ..
```

In this case you don't need to `return` an `IO a` value.

But if the process of building that computation itself requires you to perform `IO` actions, that's where you'd need such a thing. In our example, let's ask user of filename to be opened:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  act <- do
    filename <- getLine
    return (readFile filename)
  foo act
```

Here, we need a `filename` to create our action, but `getLine` is in `IO` as well. That's where additional level of `IO` comes out. Of course, this example is synthetic, as you can just do `filename <- getLine` right in `main`.

Comment: Could you add an example of what you talk about in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Jsevillamol Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, the runtime effectively discards the *result* of the `IO` action `main`, which is why it is usually defined as `IO ()`. This means that if `main` actually has a type like `IO (IO Int)`, there is no real issue. The `IO` action is executed, and the result (another `IO` action) is discarded, unexecuted.

Deeper in your program, you are more likely to just trigger a type error. For example, `fmap doSomething (return . getLine)` won't type-check if you meant `fmap doSomething getLine`.